# My signature validated on other computers are cannot found certificate

Tags: php, certificate, digital-signature, tcpdf

I've use TCPDF library to sign the pdf.
The result is okay, but when i validate on difference computer(with adobe acrobat), it's tell me that Signature Validity is UNKNOWN
the signer's identity is unknown because it has not been included in your list if trusted identities and none of its parent certificates are trusted identities.
(cannot found certification path)

How to make other computer found my cert even if not install my certificate?

i'm already bought cert from my CA...
What is the cause of the problem and how can i fix this.
This is my example signed file [here](https://o365cmu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/pannawat_n_cmu_ac_th/EuzC86ZaVxhDkMBrqiOXNaUB11jIZIwIQYSiW5mscvjPyw?e=F5M8u6)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've figured that my certificate contains 3 inner certificate chains inside 
root, intermediate, leaf cer.
In TCPDF does i need to config somewhere more?

Comment: because from [example52](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/)  at comment
/*
NOTES:
 - To create self-signed signature: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
 - To export crt to p12: openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
 - To convert pfx certificate to pem: openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes
*/

Comment: i've used the command "openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes"
it's return crt file with contains private key, leaf, intermediate, and root certificate.
i've used those file to sign my pdf.

Comment: @KJ can you tell me the program to validate?

Comment: @KJ I've added some images does the problem you remind me are related to signer identity
and certification path?

Comment: @KJ the file that you found that link is from my ex-coworker he's not maintain anymore also the source code gone as well. So, i'm doing my brand new.